# Does the Microtask Queue have more priority than the Macrotask Queue?

Tags: javascript, v8, event-loop

If the Microtask Queue has more priority than the Macrotask Queue, why the order of console logs is

- `scriptStart`
- `scriptEnd`
- `setTimeout`
- `Response`

instead of

- `scriptStart`
- `scriptEnd`
- `Response`
- `setTimeout`

given that `for(let i=0;i<100000000;i++){ const start = Date.now(); }` takes enough time to keep the main thread busy, until the response from fetch arrives?

Full Code

```js
console.log("scriptStart")

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("setTimeout");
}, 0);

fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1").then(() => {
  console.log('Response');
});

for (let i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
  const start = Date.now();
}
console.log("scriptEnd")
```

Comment: The microtask-queue doesn't have any priority system, queued microtasks will get executed as soon as the JS stack is empty, or at the next microtask checkpoint. But here the fetch.then microtask will only get queued in an other task.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in Network tab of debugger, the request to server starts only when thread was released (for loop ended). So, while `fetch` is receiving data from server, `setTimeout` has time to be done.

Comment: And also, although Promise is in Microtask queue, the question also use external resource (which is API request)

Comment: So what I don't understand is why does the browser wait for the thread to be released (for loop to end) to make the request?

Answer (score 0):

Because the interpreter is singlethreaded. It looks like you are mistaking tasks for threads. They are not. They are just a linked list of callbacks.

The interpreter works like this:

```
    START
      │
      ▼
    execute
    javascript
      │
      ▼
    Event loop
    ┌──────────┐
    │          │
    │          │
    │          ▼
    │        check if there's any  ─────────▶ handle event
    │        event completion                       │
    │          │                                    │
    │          ▼                                    │
    │        check if we need to execute  ◀─────────┘
    │        any javascript in ───────────────▶ execute
    │        the microtask list                javascript
    │          │                                    │
    │          ▼                                    │
    │        check if we need to execute  ◀─────────┘
    │        any javascript in ───────────────▶ execute
    │        the macrotask list                javascript
    │          │                                    │
    │          │                                    │
    └────◀─────┴─────────────────◀──────────────────┘
```

It's all loops. Nothing runs in parallel. So as long as you are executing javascript you are not entering the event loop.

> Note: If you are using worker_threads or webworkers then that's a different story because they really spawn threads.